# JPQL (Hibernate 4.3.6) subselect query not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem where I can easily perform two separate Queries; the first to get a Set of IDs, and the second to use those ids in an "IN" clause; but when I try to combine the two into one Query with a subselect, it does not work.

This works:

```
public List<Lead> findLeadsBySupplierAndStatus(List<Integer> supplierIds, StatusCode status){

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select ss.id from StateSupplier ss where ss.supplier.id in :supplierIds");
    query.setParameter("supplierIds", supplierIds);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Integer> result = (List<Integer>)query.getResultList();

    Query query2 = entityManager.createQuery("from Lead l where l.stateSupplier.id in :ids and l.leadStatus.id= :statusId");
    query2.setParameter("ids", result);
    query2.setParameter("statusId", status.getDbId());

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Lead> result2 = (List<Lead>)query2.getResultList();
    return result2;
}
```

but this does not:

```
public List<Lead> findLeadsBySupplierAndStatus(List<Integer> supplierIds, StatusCode status){
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select l from Lead l where l.stateSupplier.id in (select ss.id from StateSupplier ss where ss.supplier.id in :supplierIds) and l.leadStatus.id= :statusId");
    query.setParameter("supplierIds", supplierIds);
    query.setParameter("statusId", status.getDbId());

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Lead> result2 = (List<Lead>)query.getResultList();
    return result2;
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
[20 Mar 2015 17:26:28] [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1] 72277  ERROR (org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter:73) :: line 1:183: unexpected token: ,
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: ,
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:772) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.union(HqlBaseParser.java:1021) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.subQuery(HqlBaseParser.java:3857) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.compoundExpr(HqlBaseParser.java:3226) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.inList(HqlBaseParser.java:3020) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2866) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2591) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2555) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2471) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2436) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2146) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1922) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.whereClause(HqlBaseParser.java:481) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:737) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1254) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at com.chooseenergy.core.repository.LeadRepository.findLeadsBySupplierAndStatus(LeadRepository.java:158) [LeadRepository.class:?]
at com.chooseenergy.core.repository.LeadRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6d88acfd.invoke(<generated>) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:640) [spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at com.chooseenergy.core.repository.LeadRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$74954aee.findLeadsBySupplierAndStatus(<generated>) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
at com.chooseenergy.hermes.quartz.SupplierFTPDispatchJob.dispatch(SupplierFTPDispatchJob.java:71) [SupplierFTPDispatchJob.class:?]
at com.chooseenergy.hermes.quartz.SupplierFTPDispatchJob$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c96ba89a.invoke(<generated>) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708) [spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) [spring-tx-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) [spring-tx-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) [spring-tx-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644) [spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at com.chooseenergy.hermes.quartz.SupplierFTPDispatchJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$383c0773.dispatch(<generated>) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:322) [spring-context-support-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:112) [spring-context-support-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213) [quartz-2.1.6.jar:?]
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557) [quartz-2.1.6.jar:?]
```

Is there a way to make the single Query work with just JPA classes (EntityManager, Query, etc.)?

Each Lead has an FK (@ManyToOne) to a StateSupplier (stateSupplier) and a an FK (@ManyToOne) to a LeadStatus (leadStatus), and each StateSupplier has an FK (@ManyToOne) to a Supplier (supplier). I think the model is simple enough to not require source code for the Entities, as the problem is just to combine the queries, which work separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use join (explicit or implicit) in your query instead of subquery

```
select l from lead l inner join l.stateSupplier ss 
where ss.supplier.id in :suppllierIds and l.leadStatus.id =:statusId
```

Comment: The reason for the current semantics was to avoid joins between leads and stateSuppliers until I narrow down the number of stateSuppliers to the ones I am interested in. The leads and stateSuppliers I am interested in make up a very small percentage of all that are in the DB.

But I will try it out and compare what exactly is being joined in each case.

Comment: all the joins will be on foreign key indexes in the DB (if set up correctly), they should be fast. If you set log-level to fine in persistence.xml you can see the whole query and check it yourself in DB (for example explain in myslq)